# Order of growth of as function of N of the running time

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to practice algorithm complexities, How do I do this?! I don't understand the problem or what calculations I have to do to get it... ANY help would be wonderful!

```
int N = 50 ;
int sum = 0 ;
for (int n = N ; n > 0 ; n/=2 ) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        sum++ ;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the number of iterations based on `N` for the inner loop in each iteration of the outer loop such as following:

```
T(N) = N + N/2 + N/4 + ... + 1 = N (1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...+ 1/(2^log(N)) = Theta(N)
```

So, the time complexity is in `O(N)` as well.